# Node js Error: spawn node ENOENT with grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to run a simple grunt task with protractor but everytime I receive an error on the console. I am using grunt with forever utility and placed various breakpoints take narrow down the error causing code. The selenium server created a session for the test cases but the system generates the following error while trying to execute the test suite.

```
Error: spawn node ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:32)
    at child_process.js:1137:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

I cleared all the node processes and still the problem persisted. Any ideas?

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
     grunt.initConfig({
         pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
         protractor: {
           all: {
              options: {
                configFile: "conf.js",
                keepAlive: true
              }
           }
         }
     });

     grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-runner');
     grunt.registerTask('test', protractor);
};
```

my_spec.js

```
this.foreverMonitor = function(port){
     forever.list(false, function(){
         var child = new (forever.Monitor)('app.js', { 
                killTree: true,
                silent: true
                ...
         });
         child.start();
         forever.startServer(child);
     });
}

var port = 5000;
foreverMonitor(port);

browser.getSession().then(function(sess){
    console.log(sess.id);
});

describe('..', function(){
   it('..', expect());
});
```

Comment: ENOENT is typically an indicator of a missing file/directory.

Comment: missing where? in the node modules?

Comment: Presumably somewhere in your setup, but without seeing some of your code and/or grunt config I think it will be hard for anyone to answer that reliably.

Comment: Okay, so off the top of my head app.js looks like a possible culprit. What do you get if you put `console.log(require('fs').existsSync('app.js'));` right before the line `var child...`?

Comment: The output is 'false'. I had checked this earlier by adding a couple of console.logs inside the child. They worked as expected.

Comment: Forgive me if I've misunderstood something but if that outputs false then that should be the problem. Where is your app.js located in relation to your Gruntfile and my_spec.js?

Comment: I'm unable to see the file. I'm under the assumption that this file ceases to exist when the execution is complete.

Comment: I'm not too well versed in protactor so there may be something protractor specific I'm missing, but presumably the forever code here is supposed to start the app that you want to test against so 'app.js' should then point to your application's main file